# Passing parameters from uri to filters in laravel like this:

Tags: php, laravel, filter, routes

We can pass parameters from **uri** to routes in laravel like this:

```
    Route::get('/{id?}', function($id) {
    return View::make('id', $id);
});
```

Can we do the same with laravel filters like this:

```
    Route::get('/{id}', array(
    'before' => 'idfilter:{id}', function() {
        return View::make('home');
}));
```

The filter for this is:

```
Route::filter('idfilter', function($route, $request, $id) {
if ($id == 5) {
    return 'success'; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily, just get whatever you need from `Route::input('*')`.

```
Route::filter('name', function()
{
 if( Route::input('id') == 5 ){
  return 'success';
 }
}
```